# Using a picture as a hyperlink

Tags: 2007

I apologies in advance for what may be remarkably straightforward but i'm conscious i haven't the IT skills required to do this without it being spelt out. I'm using Sharepoint 2007 and quite simply i would like to put an image on a hyperlink, i.e. so that on the front page the user can click on an image of a chicken, for example, to view a page about eggs. I have been trying without success for days to do this. I have found out how to attribute an image link to a link but not how to display the image as a hyperlink?

Bits and pieces I've found have referred to code-writing and, man, that's way beyond my expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to use code in SharePoint 2007 unless you have the enterprise edition.

The best way to put this in is using the source code editor on the content editor web part.

Here is how the HTML works:

```
<a href="put the link location here"><img src="put the link to the picture here"/></a>
```

so something like

```
<a href="http://google.com"><img src="/sites/team/Documents/image.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: Hey,thanks for this. Please forgive me but we have to rewind a little to the dark ages. Can I just begin at the beginning: so, from scratch, do I create the link first and then tinker with its web part from there?

Comment: Use this step by step guide, https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/adding-pictures-with-hyperlinks-in-sharepoint.aspx